# sum input values using datejs

Tags: jquery, datejs

I am trying to grab input fields values, convert them to milliseconds, sum them all.

How can I sum hours using datejs ?

eg.

```
<input type="text" class="singleSumma" value="03:30">
<input type="text" class="singleSumma" value="02:30">
<input type="text" class="singleSumma" value="03:45">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".singleSumma").each( function(){ 
        var singleSummaVal= $(this).val();              
             if (singleSummaVal) {                                      
                var ssv = Date.parse(singleSummaVal).getTime();
                           //how to sum input values using datejs?
                           // result= ssv.add(ssv);                         


            }           
    }); 
});
</script>
```

**Solution** by geoffrey.mcgill

```
var t = Date.today();
var sum= 0 ;

$(".singleSumma").each(function() {             
    var singleSummaVal = $(this).val();
       if (singleSummaVal) {
        var ssv = Date.parse(singleSummaVal);
        sum += (ssv - t);
            var ts = new TimeSpan(sum);

           console.log(ts.hours + ":" + ts.minutes);
      }
});
```

Comment: You've read the documentation of course, right? Then you already know that [you've got a Javascript Date after the call to `.parse`](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parse), and therefore that [`getTime()` gives you a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) .. and we all know how to add numbers together, right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, i do not not how to do it with datejs/timejs using .add() function

Comment: If you don't know what `.add()` does then why do you think you need it? What's wrong with `+`?

Comment: You need to define what you want to sum, starting from where. Do you want to sum the hours from 00:00, or from the year 1970? Or, do you want to sum the milliseconds from 00:00? What exactly are you trying to determine?

Comment: @geoffrey.mcgill I would like to sum input fields values as hours, eg. 03:30 + 02:30 + 03:45 = 9:45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the value in milliseconds for each value from the start of the Day. Then add all those millisecond values together and pass into a new TimeSpan object. The TimeSpan will then calculate the number of days, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

The following sample demonstrates the entire scenario.

**Example**

```
var d1 = Date.parse('03:30'),
    d2 = Date.parse('02:30'),
    d3 = Date.parse('03:45'),
    t = Date.today();

var sum = (d1 - t) + (d2 - t) + (d3 - t);

var ts = new TimeSpan(sum);

console.log('hours', ts.hours); // 9
console.log('minutes', ts.minutes); // 45
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works as you suggest it, I have update the first post. Thank you!

Comment: A list of DateJS format specifiers is available at https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers

Answer (score 0):

Try use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var totalSum = 0;
    $(".singleSumma").each( function(){ 
        var singleSummaVal= $(this).val();              
            if (singleSummaVal) {                                       
                var ssv = Date.parse(singleSummaVal).getTime();
                totalSum += ssv; 
            }           
    }); 
    alert('ts in seconds' + totalSum ); 
    // or if you like other time properties
    var sumDT = new Date();
    sumDT.setTime(totalSum);    
});
</script>
```

Comment: `code`totalSum += ssv;`code` gave me wrong result, I think I must use datejs function .add()